# Write email php, escaping html characters

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a html for email and i would like to send it using PHP. But saving it in a variable it gives me a lot of errors.

How can I save so mutch html and css in php variable, is there any way?

Here is the code, it is not complete:

```
<?php 
  $corpo='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <!-- NAME: 1 COLUMN - BANDED -->
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{
                height:100% !important;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width:100% !important;
            }
            table{
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
            img,a img{
                border:0;
                outline:none;
                text-decoration:none;
            }
            h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            p{
                margin:1em 0;
                padding:0;
            }
            a{
                word-wrap:break-word;
            }
            .ReadMsgBody{
                width:100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass{
                width:100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div{
                line-height:100%;
            }
            table,td{
                mso-table-lspace:0pt;
                mso-table-rspace:0pt;
            }
            #outlook a{
                padding:0;
            }
            img{
                -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
            }
            body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote{
                -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
                -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
            }
            #bodyCell{
                padding:0;
            }
            .mcnImage{
                vertical-align:bottom;
            }
            .mcnTextContent img{
                height:auto !important;
            }
        /*
        @tab Page
        @section background style
        @tip Set the background color and top border for your email. You may want to choose colors that match your companys branding.
        */
            body,#bodyTable{
                /*@editable*/background-color:#F2F2F2;
            }
            h3{
                /*@editable*/color:#606060 !important;
                display:block;
                /*@editable*/font-family:Helvetica;
                /*@editable*/font-size:18px;
                /*@editable*/font-style:normal;
                /*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
                /*@editable*/line-height:125%;
                /*@editable*/letter-spacing:-.5px;
                margin:0;
                /*@editable*/text-align:left;
            }
        /*
        @tab Page
        @section heading 4
        @tip Set the styling for all fourth-level headings in your emails. These should be the smallest of your headings.
        @style heading 4
        */
            h4{
                /*@editable*/color:#808080 !important;
                display:block;
                /*@editable*/font-family:Helvetica;
                /*@editable*/font-size:16px;
                /*@editable*/font-style:normal;
                /*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
                /*@editable*/line-height:125%;
                /*@editable*/letter-spacing:normal;
                margin:0;
                /*@editable*/text-align:left;
            }
        /*
        @tab Preheader
        @section preheader style
        @tip Set the background color and borders for your emails preheader area.
        */
            #templatePreheader{
                /*@editable*/background-color:#FFFFFF;
                /*@editable*/border-top:0;
                /*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
            }
        /*
        @tab Preheader
        @section preheader text
        @tip Set the styling for your emails preheader text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
        */
            .preheaderContainer .mcnTextContent,.preheaderContainer .mcnTextContent p{
                /*@editable*/color:#606060;
                /*@editable*/font-family:Helvetica;
                /*@editable*/font-size:11px;
                /*@editable*/line-height:125%;
                /*@editable*/text-align:left;
            }
        /*
        @tab Preheader
        @section preheader link
        @tip Set the styling for your emails header links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
            .preheaderContainer .mcnTextContent a{
                /*@editable*/color:#606060;
                /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
                /*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
            }
        /*
        @tab Header
        @section header style
        @tip Set the background color and borders for your emails header area.
        */
            #templateHeader{
                /*@editable*/background-color:#FFFFFF;
                /*@editable*/border-top:0;
                /*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
            }
        /*
        @tab Header
        @section header text
        @tip Set the styling for your emails header text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
        */
            .headerContainer .mcnTextContent,.headerContainer .mcnTextContent p{
                /*@editable*/color:#606060;
                /*@editable*/font-family:Helvetica;
                /*@editable*/font-size:15px;
                /*@editable*/line-height:150%;
                /*@editable*/text-align:left;
            }
        /*
        @tab Header
        @section header link
        @tip Set the styling for your emails header links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
            .headerContainer .mcnTextContent a{
                /*@editable*/color:#6DC6DD;
                /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
                /*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
            }
        /*
        @tab Body
        @section body style
        @tip Set the background color and borders for your emails body area.
        */
            #templateBody{
                /*@editable*/background-color:#FFFFFF;
                /*@editable*/border-top:0;
                /*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
            }
        /*
        @tab Body
        @section body text
        @tip Set the styling for your emails body text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
        */
            .bodyContainer .mcnTextContent,.bodyContainer .mcnTextContent p{
                /*@editable*/color:#606060;
                /*@editable*/font-family:Helvetica;
                /*@editable*/font-size:15px;
                /*@editable*/line-height:150%;
                /*@editable*/text-align:left;
            }
        /*
        @tab Body
        @section body link
        @tip Set the styling for your emails body links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
            .bodyContainer .mcnTextContent a{
                /*@editable*/color:#6DC6DD;
                /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
                /*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
            }
        /*
        @tab Footer
        @section footer style
        @tip Set the background color and borders for your emails footer area.
        */
            #templateFooter{
                /*@editable*/background-color:#F2F2F2;
                /*@editable*/border-top:0;
                /*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
            }
        /*
        @tab Footer
        @section footer text
        @tip Set the styling for your emails footer text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
        */
            .footerContainer .mcnTextContent,.footerContainer .mcnTextContent p{
                /*@editable*/color:#606060;
                /*@editable*/font-family:Helvetica;
                /*@editable*/font-size:11px;
                /*@editable*/line-height:125%;
                /*@editable*/text-align:left;
            }
        /*
        @tab Footer
        @section footer link
        @tip Set the styling for your emails footer links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
            .footerContainer .mcnTextContent a{
                /*@editable*/color:#606060;
                /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
                /*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
            }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote{
                -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            body{
                width:100% !important;
                min-width:100% !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            table[class=mcnTextContentContainer]{
                width:100% !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            table[class=mcnBoxedTextContentContainer]{
                width:100% !important;
            }

    }

    }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            td[class=mcnImageCardTopImageContent]{
                padding-top:18px !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            table[class=mcnCaptionLeftContentOuter] td[class=mcnTextContent],table[class=mcnCaptionRightContentOuter] td[class=mcnTextContent]{
                padding-top:9px !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            td[class=mcnCaptionBlockInner] table[class=mcnCaptionTopContent]:last-child td[class=mcnTextContent]{
                padding-top:18px !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            td[class=mcnBoxedTextContentColumn]{
                padding-left:18px !important;
                padding-right:18px !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            td[class=mcnTextContent]{
                padding-right:18px !important;
                padding-left:18px !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        /*
        @tab Mobile Styles
        @section Preheader Visibility
        @tip Set the visibility of the emails preheader on small screens. You can hide it to save space.
        */
            table[id=templatePreheader]{
                /*@editable*/display:block !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        /*
        @tab Mobile Styles
        @section Preheader Text
        @tip Make the preheader text larger in size for better readability on small screens.
        */
            td[class=preheaderContainer] td[class=mcnTextContent],td[class=preheaderContainer] td[class=mcnTextContent] p{
                /*@editable*/font-size:14px !important;
                /*@editable*/line-height:115% !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        /*
        @tab Mobile Styles
        @section Header Text
        @tip Make the header text larger in size for better readability on small screens.
        */
            td[class=headerContainer] td[class=mcnTextContent],td[class=headerContainer] td[class=mcnTextContent] p{
                /*@editable*/font-size:18px !important;
                /*@editable*/line-height:125% !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        /*
        @tab Mobile Styles
        @section Body Text
        @tip Make the body text larger in size for better readability on small screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
        */
            td[class=bodyContainer] td[class=mcnTextContent],td[class=bodyContainer] td[class=mcnTextContent] p{
                /*@editable*/font-size:18px !important;
                /*@editable*/line-height:125% !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        /*
        @tab Mobile Styles
        @section footer text
        @tip Make the body content text larger in size for better readability on small screens.
        */
            td[class=footerContainer] td[class=mcnTextContent],td[class=footerContainer] td[class=mcnTextContent] p{
                /*@editable*/font-size:14px !important;
                /*@editable*/line-height:115% !important;
            }

    }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            td[class=footerContainer] a[class=utilityLink]{
                display:block !important;
            }

    }</style></head>
        <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
            <center>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">
                            <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                                        <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateHeader">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="templateContainer">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td valign="top" class="headerContainer" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnImageBlock">
        <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding:9px" class="mcnImageBlockInner">
                        <table align="left" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right: 9px; padding-left: 9px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;">


                                            <img align="left" alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/09dc4b1b18f3f16d3f259eb11/images/803e3bf6-65ed-46f0-8786-cfd7b1a84e4e.png" width="500" style="max-width:500px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" class="mcnImage">


                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <!-- // END HEADER -->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                                        <!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateBody">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="templateContainer">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td valign="top" class="bodyContainer" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnTextBlock">
        <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="mcnTextBlockInner">

                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="mcnTextContentContainer">
                        <tbody><tr>

                            <td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:9px; padding-right: 18px; padding-bottom: 9px; padding-left: 18px;">

                                <h1>Designing Your Email</h1>

    <h3>Creating an elegant email is simple</h3>

    <p>Now that you’ve selected a template to work with, drag in content blocks to define the structure of your message. Don’t worry, you can always delete or rearrange blocks as needed. Then click “Design” to define fonts, colors, and styles.</p>

    <p>Need inspiration for your design? <a class="mc-template-link" href="http://inspiration.mailchimp.com">Here’s what other MailChimp users are doing.</a></p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnFollowBlock">
        <tbody class="mcnFollowBlockOuter">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:9px" class="mcnFollowBlockInner">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnFollowContentContainer">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding-left:9px;padding-right:9px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnFollowContent" style="border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;background-color: #FAFAFA;">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px; padding-right:9px; padding-left:9px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td valign="top">


                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnFollowStacked">

                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/investemais" target="_blank"><img src="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-facebook-96.png" alt="Facebook" class="mcnFollowBlockIcon" width="48" style="width:48px; max-width:48px; display:block;"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>


                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowTextContent" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:9px;">
                                                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/investemais" target="_blank" style="color: #606060;font-family: Arial;font-size: 11px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;">Facebook</a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                </tbody></table>


                                    <!--[if gte mso 6]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    <![endif]-->


                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnFollowStacked">

                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                            <a href="https://twitter.com/InvesteMais" target="_blank"><img src="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-twitter-96.png" alt="Twitter" class="mcnFollowBlockIcon" width="48" style="width:48px; max-width:48px; display:block;"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>


                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowTextContent" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:9px;">
                                                            <a href="https://twitter.com/InvesteMais" target="_blank" style="color: #606060;font-family: Arial;font-size: 11px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;">Twitter</a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                </tbody></table>


                                    <!--[if gte mso 6]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    <![endif]-->


                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnFollowStacked">

                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/investe-mais" target="_blank"><img src="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-linkedin-96.png" alt="LinkedIn" class="mcnFollowBlockIcon" width="48" style="width:48px; max-width:48px; display:block;"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>


                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowTextContent" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:9px;">
                                                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/investe-mais" target="_blank" style="color: #606060;font-family: Arial;font-size: 11px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;">LinkedIn</a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                </tbody></table>


                                    <!--[if gte mso 6]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    <![endif]-->


                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnFollowStacked">

                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right:0; padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                            <a href="http://investemais.pt" target="_blank"><img src="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-link-96.png" alt="Website" class="mcnFollowBlockIcon" width="48" style="width:48px; max-width:48px; display:block;"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>


                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowTextContent" style="padding-right:0; padding-bottom:9px;">
                                                            <a href="http://investemais.pt" target="_blank" style="color: #606060;font-family: Arial;font-size: 11px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;">Website</a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                </tbody></table>


                                    <!--[if gte mso 6]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    <![endif]-->

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <!-- // END BODY -->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- // END TEMPLATE -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </body>
    </html>' ; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Please remove the snippet as it won't work with php

Comment: didn't understand what you mean, sorry i'm a bit new at php.

Comment: I just want to know how to save in a php variable a lot of html and css code to send an email

Comment: Is that a Mailchimp template? If it is, doesn't it seem easier to just use the Mailchimp API to send the email for you?

Comment: @PedroPiloto: do you need further help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) for such things. If you turn on output buffering, everything you print out will be "buffered" (= stored) instead of printed out to the user. You can then get the buffer and save it in e.g. a variable.

**Why should you do this?**

With output buffering you can use PHP as a "simple template engine". What that means is, that you can create template files containing HTML and even PHP.

**A simple example:**

`email_template.php` (Using [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My name is <?=$test?></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in your script where you render the e-mail bodies:

```
$test = "Pedro Piloto";
ob_start();
require('email_template.php');
$body = ob_get_clean();
```

The h1 tag would then contain "My name is Pedro Piloto".